# Taking Moments About a Point

Tags: classical-mechanics

This is a rod attached to a wall by a light inextensible string:

[image: problem]
And here is a diagram showing the forces acting:

[image: forces]

I want to find the normal reaction $R$ between the rod and wall using moments about $C$.

A moment is the product of the force times the perpendicular distance from the pivot.  So the moment created by $R$ is $R * 2$.  Though I cannot find any other perpendicular forces acting in the opposite way to use the principle of moments.

The mark scheme for this problem says that $R(2) = 3g\cos30$, but $3g$ acts parallel to the direction that we measured $R$ from.  So I do not see how we can even include $3g$ because resolving it through $\cos30$ makes it perpendicular to the rod, but not the direction we measured the distance for $R$.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand moments about $C$. You take the product of the force and the perpendicular distance of its line of action from $C$. So here that perpendicular distance is $1\cdot\cos30^o$ for the gravitational force.

Comment: Ah, okay, now its clicked.  Thanks.